# Docker unable to run a shell script inside a container using dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am facing a highly trivial problem wherein the shell script "httpd-service.sh" is not getting executed in the below Dockerfile.

```
FROM localhost:5000/httpd_custom_image:v6
WORKDIR /opt
ADD httpd-service.sh .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/sh","/opt/httpd-service.sh"]
```

Below is the content of the httpd-service.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
```

The script httpd-service.sh is getting copied inside /opt in container and has permissions.

Below is the docker version,

```
[root@vfecare-3 temp]# docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8
```

Can someone let me know what is breaking here?

Comment: Does 'docker run' return any logs?

Comment: Are you sure it does not run or can it be that it returns immediately because `httpd` is a daemon process (and should also return immediately)? In the latter case your container would immediately terminate

Comment: as a test, replace `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd` with `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd && sleep infinity` build again and launch

Comment: docker run returns the container ID, and docker logs <CONTAINER_ID> returns nothing.

Comment: @OlegSklyar, I tried with the approach u suggested and now i see that http is running when i spin the container using "docke run". Does this mean that the command gets executed and then gets terminated immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working in the foreground with the below lines in the Dockerfile.

```
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]
```

Comment: So to follow up on my original comment: docker requires a foreground process, the container will quit as soon as the process under `CMD` terminates so daemons either have to be run in foreground, as you now configured, or need to be followed by some foreground process that does not terminate (e.g. `tail -f /somelogfile`). WRT your solution, I would keep `-d foreground` as arguments to `CMD` leaving the `ENTRYPOINT` unchanged as now you cannot start your container without actually starting `httpd`, which might be useful for debugging